# Find a value in a range of cells as a substring

Tags: excel

On tab 1, I have a column where each cell in that column has a group of numbers, and another column where that group of numbers is associated with a name.
Example:

```
A1: 131,210,312,419,5010 B1: Jim
A2: 210,311,517,614,701  B2: Tom
A3: 51,120,210           B3: Sam
A4: 311,701,1012         B4: Tim
```

On tab 2, I have a column of numbers.
Example:

```
A1: 131
A2: 210
A3: 120
A4: 42
```

Next to each number, I want to return the name associated with the first list which contains the number.  So in this example, it should be...

```
A1: 131  B1: Jim
A2: 210  B2: Jim
A3: 120  B3: Sam
A4: 42   B4: N/A
```

I'm thinking find or vlookup might be involved, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it come together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve a true match, you must enforce the condition that each value looked for will begin and end with a comma. This string concatenation together with the wildcards will necessitate an *array formula*.

[image: INDEX(MATCH()) with wildcards]

The array formula in E1 is `=INDEX('Tab 1'!$B$1:$B$4,MATCH("*,"&D1&",*",","&'Tab 1'!$A$1:$A$4&",",0))`. This requires *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* rather than simply *Enter*. Once entered correctly, it can be filled down as necessary. You may wish to apply an `IFERROR` wrapper to show an empty string instead os `#N/A`.

Comment: @pnuts - Good point. That string concatenation could quickly make adding the worksheet name in pretty ugly. I've edited my formula and graphic in my response to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Entered as an array formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter) and copied down, this works:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&D8&",",","&$A$1:$A$4&",")),0))
```

[image]