# Find value in range of cells, then return index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question might already have been asked, but I can't find the right answer, so... Please apologize.

In Excel, I got a big array of key / value data in two separate cells, like :

```
ID1 toto;tata;tutu
ID2 lolo;lala;lulu
...
```

I need the formula that will return ID1 if I search toto or tata or tutu, ID2 if I search lolo or lala or lulu.

Comment: actually I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617873/find-a-value-in-a-range-of-cells-as-a-substring?rq=1. It could work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula to search all cells and return the row that the string is in. It is then an index match to find the ID it refers to. As it is an array formula you need to use ctrl+shift+enter when you enter the formula.

```
=INDEX(A2:A3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(UPPER(C2),UPPER(B2:B3))),0))
```

Where the ID values are in column A, the text strings are in column B and in cell C2 you type the text value you are looking for.
[image]